# Issue with space in qt pro file

Tags: qt, windows

I want to add macro (make constant) of the application name in qt pro file and use it later in code. For example:

```
QMAKE_TARGET_NAME = Foo Bar
DEFINES += APP_NAME=\\\"$$QMAKE_TARGET_NAME\\\"
```

When I use: qDebug() << APP_NAME it shows only "Foo". How to escape space in qt pro file? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DEFINES += APP_NAME=$$shell_quote($$QMAKE_TARGET_NAME)`

or if the `"` should be part of the define, then

`DEFINES += APP_NAME=$$shell_quote(\"$$QMAKE_TARGET_NAME\")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ha, very nice! Learned something new, I've always manually escaped, Thanks!

Comment: Is there way to make it also compatible with Visual Studio 2015?